# Getting USB info using SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I am trying to get the SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW method to work but without success.

The P/Invoke is declared as:

```
// Device Property
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct DEVPROPKEY
{
    public Guid fmtid;
    public UInt32 pid;
}
/// <summary>
/// Provides details about a single USB device.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
internal struct DeviceInterfaceData
{
    public int Size;
    public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
    public int Flags;
    public UIntPtr Reserved;
}

[DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(
        IntPtr deviceInfoSet,
        ref DeviceInterfaceData DeviceInfoData,
        ref DEVPROPKEY propertyKey,
        out UInt64 propertyType, // or Uint32 ?
        IntPtr propertyBuffer, // or byte[]
        uint propertyBufferSize,
        out uint requiredSize,
        UInt32 flags);

/// <summary>
/// Gets a new key for the bus reported device description.
/// </summary>
internal static DEVPROPKEY DEVPKEY_Device_BusReportedDeviceDesc
{
    get
    {
        DEVPROPKEY key = new DEVPROPKEY();
        key.pid = 4;
        key.fmtid = new Guid((uint)0x540b947e, (ushort)0x8b40, (ushort)0x45bc, 0xa8, 0xa2, 0x6a, 0x0b, 0x89, 0x4c, 0xbd, 0xa2);
        return key;
    }
}
```

I am calling with:

```
uint propertyRegDataType = 0;
uint requiredSize = 0;
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024);
if (UnsafeNativeMethods.SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW(infoSet, ref deviceInterfaceData, ref devicePropertyKey, out propertyType, buffer, 1024, out requiredSize, 0))
{
}
else
{
    int test = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); // returns 87 - invalid parameter
}
```

infoSet has a value from:

```
IntPtr infoSet = UnsafeNativeMethods.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref hidGuid, null, IntPtr.Zero, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
```

deviceInterfaceData has values including a GUID for the interface and that comes from:

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(infoSet, 0, ref hidGuid, (uint)i, ref deviceInterfaceData);
```

hidGuid is from (where result is a Guid object:

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.HidD_GetHidGuid(out result);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, I have just realised that I am using the DeviceInterfaceData when I should be using the DeviceInfoData which is derived from SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo call.  Duw

Comment: Please delete your question if you don't need further assistance.